# How to get a plugin and flexform in typoscript?

Tags: typo3, typoscript

Is it possible to get a plugin called with a flexform value?

```
temp.whatever = HTML
temp.whatever < plugin.tx_myplugin_pi1
```

Problem is i have a selectbox with two different templates to show:

```
$this->pi_getFFvalue($this->cObj->data['pi_flexform']
```

returns "Template1" or "Template2" for example

Comment: right now im using the "default" case of the switch to display the right template. without any special setting in typoscript. not the best way, but a way to solve my problem

Comment: are you using templavoila?